# Local clipping of planes based on local axis

Tags: three.js, clipping

I was trying to clip left half of a planeBuffer using material.clippingPlanes.
When the object is at center with rotation (0,0,0) then the clipping works.

```
object.material.clippingPlanes =
[object.getWorldDirection().cross(object.up).normalize(), object.position.z )];
```

But this code fails when the object is at a non-zero position with non-zero rotation and the cut does not change with orientation of object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Material.clippingPlanes](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material.clippingPlanes):

> User-defined clipping planes specified as THREE.Plane objects in **world space**.

Because the planes are in **world space**, they won't orient within your object's local space. You would need to apply your object's world transformation matrix to the planes in order to align them with your object.

```
myMesh.material.clippingPlanes[0].applyMatrix4(myMesh.matrixWorld);
```

Note that if your mesh is moving around, you'd need to store the original clipping plane for application of the new `matrixWorld` from each transformation.

```
// somehwere else in the code:
var clipPlane1 = new THREE.Plane(); // however you configure it is up to you

// later, probably in your render method:
myMesh.material.clippingPlanes[0].copy(clipPlane1);
myMesh.material.clippingPlanes[0].applyMatrix4(myMesh.matrixWorld);
```

Comment: Thanks.
I also had to move the plane using

object.material.clippingPlanes[0].constant -= object.material.clippingPlanes[0].distanceToPoint(object.position);

Comment: @AmriteshAnand Good catch! Thanks for sharing that extra info. :)